# Group By Having issue returning same number of rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I want to get the ids / rows for the max last_updated_date, but the query is returning the same number of rows

```
    id   |  job_number | last_udated_date
    1407;"88212";"2015-12-16 00:00:00+05:30"
    77;"48439";"2015-12-16 00:00:00+05:30"
    1526;"1484924208";"2017-01-21 00:00:00+05:30"
    1527;"1484924208";"2017-01-21 00:00:00+05:30"
    1528;"1484924208";"2017-01-21 00:00:00+05:30"
    1529;"1484924208";"2017-01-22 07:20:42.586+05:30"
```

The query should return only 1407,77, 1529, but now its returning all the values

The query:

```
select id, last_updated_date 
from brs.events 
where last_updated_date in (select max(last_updated_date) 
                            from brs.events 
                            group by last_updated_date )
```

Comment: Please clarify why those three should be in the output?

Comment: Because I want to get the get all the latest the job numbers on which the user has worked on, so there are 3 distinct job numbers user has worked on in 3 ditinct days

Comment: see the UPDATE in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do this:

```
SELECT id,
  last_updated_date
FROM brs.events
WHERE last_updated_date =
  (SELECT MAX(last_updated_date) FROM brs.events
  )
```

If you want to get only one row based on latest last_update_date, you can use LIMIT for this:

```
select id
from brs.events
order by last_update_date desc
limit 1;
```

**UPDATE** for latest changes in the question:

```
select
    id,
    last_updated_date
from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over (partition by job_number order by last_updated_date desc) rn
    from your_table t
) t where rn = 1;
```

Comment: If I want to get only those records based on latest last_updated_date. There are 1 to 1529 records in that table. I want to get all the records but only one row based on latest_updated_date.

Comment: *get all the records but only one row* - Doesn't make any sense. Can you clarify it a bit?

Comment: There are 1529 records in that table, but your query returns only 1 row

Comment: @sromit what do you want it to return? 1 to 1528 rows? Please clarify it in the question. Expected output in the form of a table would help.

Comment: I want to get all the rows, but I dont want any duplicate records for a day where job_number is equal, basically the user can create same job_number in a day at different time

Comment: I want to get 1407, 77, and 1529 in my resultset

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133741/discussion-between-sromit-and-gurv).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, the ideal option would be [`DISTINCT ON()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) because it makes the query really simple.

> SELECT DISTINCT ON ( expression [, ...] ) keeps only the first row of
>   each set of rows where the given expressions evaluate to equal

```
select distinct on (job_no) id
      ,job_no
      ,max(lpd)
from evnts
group by job_no,id
```

[`Demo`](http://rextester.com/GZFSG79977)

Here, `Distinct on` will evaluate rows in each group(`job_number`)

Comment: If i want to get select * , this will not work, as there are other columns for which I also need data

Comment: I wrote this solution based on your question, you should be very clear when writing a question to get a better answer

Comment: Thanx @wingedpanther..sure will keep in mind..but now I want all the rows distinct on all job no. and also on the latest lpd